# Two separate stores in a single application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a `vue.js` application which contains a landing page, user dashboard, and an admin dashboard. All of them have mostly different states, they only share a single `shared` module with things like page width, token, current user, etc.

The problem is that vuex allowed to have just one centralized store, which means anyone who goes to a landing page can see the whole store structure, which could be a potential security issue.

The perfect solution would be something like this:

```
store: Object.merge({}, SharedStore, UserDashboardStore),
```

and in another place:

```
store: Object.merge({}, SharedStore, AdminDashboardStore),
```

where a variable here is an `Vuex.Store` instance.

But it doesn't work obviously. Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Vuex allows you to separate stores into modules. Take a look at this article which might help for your use case. https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html

Comment: This question might need some clarification. A user can't go into Devtools and dig through the Vuex Store when the application is deployed in Production mode. The only time anyone would see whats in the store would be if that information is included in the view - in which case that information should be locked behind authentication. So can you clarify on exactly where the security issue is?

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I misunderstand your question, but can't you just create multiple stores?
I would also caution you to remember that anything client side should be assumed that a user can access it. So don't go storing things client side if its related to security.

```
~/store/admin/actions.js
~/store/admin/getters.js
~/store/admin/mutations.js
~/store/admin/state.js
~/store/admin/store.js
~/store/user/actions.js
~/store/user/getters.js
~/store/user/mutations.js
~/store/user/state.js
~/store/user/store.js
~/store/actions.js
~/store/getters.js
~/store/mutations.js
~/store/state.js
~/store/store.js
```

~/store/store.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import state from "./state"
import getters from "./getters"
import mutations from "./mutations"
import actions from "./actions"
import moduleAdmin from './admin/store.js'
import moduleUser from './user/store.js'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    getters,
    mutations,
    state,
    actions,
    modules: {
        admin: moduleAdmin,
        user: moduleUser,
    },
    strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
})
```

~/store/admin/store.js

```js
import state from './state.js'
import getters from './getters.js'
import actions from './actions.js'
import mutations from './mutations.js'

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: state,
    getters: getters,
    actions: actions,
    mutations: mutations,
}
```

then access as needed:

```js
return this.$store.state.someVariable;
return this.$store.state.admin.someVariable;
return this.$store.state.user.someVariable;
```